# Clojure TCP Server with Aleph

Tags: tcp, clojure, netty

I am attempting to write a simple TCP server using Aleph.  Everything works fine, except I am unsure of how I should detect when a channel has been closed.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/ztellman/aleph/wiki/TCP):

> When the client closes the connection, both sides of the channel will be immediately sealed.  The final message from the channel will be nil

However, I never seem to receive this final `nil` message.  If I inspect the channel, I do see that it has been closed.  Here is my code:

```
(use 'lamina.core 'aleph.tcp 'gloss.core)

(defn process-msg [ch msg]
  (if (closed? ch)
    (println "Channel has been closed") ;This never happens
    (do-some-processing msg)))

(start-tcp-server
  (fn [ch client-info]
    (receive-all ch
      (partial process-msg ch))
  {:port 10000, :frame (string :utf-8 :delimiters ["\n"])})
```

Should I be doing something differently?  Is my frame keeping the nil message from being processed?  I could have a separate thread monitoring my channels and checking whether or not they have been closed, but this seems like a poor design.  I would prefer to use Aleph, but right now its looking like I will need to use a raw Netty handler.  Using Netty directly would be fine, but I'd prefer to use Aleph if possible since it feels a little more idiomatic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To register a callback for when a channel is closed or drained, use (on-closed ch callback) or (on-drained ch callback), which both take a callback with zero arguments.

https://github.com/ztellman/lamina/wiki/Channels

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for.  I didn't think to check the Lamina documentation.